# Solving problem of component failing to rerender after refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect

I have a Dashboard component that receives state from a reducer and then renders account info for a user based on state. The component is rendering just fine on the first render. However, when I refresh the page, everything goes away, nothing is rendering. I thought it might be a problem with my useEffect hook and that this problem could possibly be solved by placing some value inside the dependency array there. However, I'm realizing that even if the problem were that, the portions of the component JSX elements that are not dependent on the useEffect hook should still render. Not even that is happening, I'm getting absolutely nothing on refresh. How can I resolve this?

Here is a link to the project on Github: https://github.com/jevoncochran/Food-Truck-TrackR

Here is the component:

```
const Dashboard = props => {
    const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
            axiosWithAuth()
                .get(`/operator/${props.id}`)
                .then(res => {
                    // console.log(res);
                    setAccountInfo(res.data);
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [props.id])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is the Dashboard component</h1>
            <h2>Welcome, {accountInfo.username}</h2>
            <h3>Your Trucks</h3>
            {accountInfo.trucks && accountInfo.trucks.map(truck => (
                <div key={truck.id}>
                    <p>{truck.name}</p>
                    <p>{truck.cuisine_type}</p>
                    <p>{truck.physical_address}</p>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        id: state.account.id,
        username: state.account.username,
        email: state.account.email
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Dashboard);
```

EDIT:
This is how the Dashboard component is being rendered. After reading over folks comments, it seems like upon refresh, I'm losing state.account.id which is causing me to lose the dynamicRoute in App.js, which causes the Dashboard component to fail to render. Anyone see a solution for this problem:

```
function App(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const dynamicRoute = `/api/vendor/${props.accountId}`

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <PrivateRoute path={dynamicRoute} component={Dashboard} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you also getting any error?

Comment: Yes its happens because when you are refreshing page redux state is goes away. Maybe you need to use redux-persist https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist to save existing state when you refresh page.

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb No error, just a blank page.

Comment: @Tazoleladze Hmmm I'm confused though. That would make more sense to me if only the elements dependent on redux state weren't rendering. However, I'm not getting anything, not even that h1 tag that just renders "This is the Dashboard component." That wouldn't be dependent on redux state, right?

Comment: @Tazoleladze Wait, does the fact that the component is in the connect function mean that the entire component rendering is dependent upon redux state?

Comment: No is not depending on redux state. I'm 99% sure the problem should be shown in when component rendering. Do you can to upload full example on `codesandbox` or `github` to be able to find a problem?

Comment: I'm confused between 'first render' and 'refreshing the page' - how are they different?

Comment: @Tazoleladze Here is the app on Github: https://github.com/jevoncochran/Food-Truck-TrackR

Comment: @WillJenkins when a user logs in successfully, it routes them to the Dashboard page and renders what's there successfully. That's what I mean by first render. If I manually refresh the page in the browser, everything goes away. Do you understand?

Comment: My guess is that the props aren't passed when you refresh the page, (you could log the props to see if that is the case) , what you could do is save the id to localStorage before redirecting to the dashboard and in the dashboard Component get the item from localStorage rather than the props

Comment: So assuming you're already authorised, is there a fetch for the account details somewhere in the app startup code?

Comment: @AbdullahAbid After a refresh, the Dashboard component won't render at all so when I put a console.log in there to get the props, it won't log. It's not just that it won't run the useEffect hook or it won't pass props. It's literally as if the component doesn't exist after refreshing. I'm so lost.

Comment: What is rendering `Dashboard` then? Seems after the page reload that app state changes and the dashboard isn't mounted. If it was then any console.logs in that component would execute.

Comment: @DrewReese Dashboard is being rendered from a route in App.js. Check the edit I just made to the original post for the code.

Comment: Shouldn't your dynamic route path be something more along the lines of `"/api/vendor/:accountId"` so the account id is specified as a route match param?

Comment: @DrewReese That's exactly what the path is, though: const dynamicRoute = `/api/vendor/${props.accountId}`

Comment: Defining the path for the route to match and constructing a path to navigate to it are not the same thing. I.e. the route path is `"/api/vendor/:accountId"`, but to navigate to it is `/api/vendor/${props.accountId}` to make `"/api/vendor/123456789"`, and within the dashboard/component on `props.match.params.accountId` is the value `123456789`.

Comment: @DrewReese Okay, I see what you're saying. I fixed the route to allow for a match and now, the Dashboard component is at least rendering on refresh. But I still need to figure out how to get the account on refresh because I'm still losing account state.

Comment: Take a look at `redux-presist` https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist the redux-presist would maintain the state on refresh instead of resetting it

Comment: Yes you need to use redux-persist, or you can also save `res.data.account` in `localStorage` when `loginAndGetAccount` dispatched and when the user refreshs the page you need to check did I have a `token` in localStorage? If yes then also you have account and dispatch a `GET_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS` action. Also you need to add something like `isInitialized` which is default to `true` inside `truckReducer` and don't  render anything in `App` component while `isInitialized` is equal to true. I think you explained correctly, excuse me for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple ways to solve this problem. One of them was to have an action that would make an API call to retrieve the info I needed for the Dashboard component and run that action if ever the redux state was coming back undefined, which is what happens on refresh. There's also redux-persist. I ultimately ended up using redux-persist to solve this problem, for which documentation can be found here: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist. Here is the code from `index.js`:

The relevant imports:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
```

```
// set up to persist redux state on refresh
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, truckReducer);

// async middleware (thunk) and logger has to go here
let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));

let persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        {/* wrap component in PersistGate for redux persist to take effect */}
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <Router>
                <App />
            </Router>
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```